# Migrating to Base Sepolia, SAFE AA contracts reverts with reason `GS104`

Tags: safe-core, account-abstraction

I'm running in an issue migrating from Base Goerli --> Sepolia.
TL;DR: The exact same TX works on Goerli, not Sepolia.

I'm running code to deploy a NFT factory, leveraging PRIVY, PIMLICO & SAFE for a signless and gasless experience.

- Sepolia: `0x8b92B25A6E660D602954E59fF74E415656b29b1E`
- Goerli: `0xb4012E07568FB7086F4EFdd11A4cA9a69110800C`

AFAIK, those contracts are the exact same.

In this case I'm trying to use the `'deploy'` function.
We create a PIMLICO smart account as such:

```typescript
// embeddedWallet is a Privy embedded wallet
const ethereumProvider = embeddedWallet.provider

// chainStr is either 'base-goerli' or 'base-sepolia' 
const PIMLICO_PAYMASTER = `https://api.pimlico.io/v2/${chainStr}/rpc?apikey=${api-key}`
const PIMLICO_BUNDLER = `https://api.pimlico.io/v1/${chainStr}/rpc?apikey=${api-key}`

const accounts = await ethereumProvider.request({
  method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
})

const walletClient = await createWalletClient({
  account: accounts[0],
  chain: chain,
  transport: custom(ethereumProvider),
})
const pimlicoPaymaster = createPimlicoPaymasterClient({
  transport: http(PIMLICO_PAYMASTER),
})
const customSigner = walletClientToCustomSigner(walletClient)
const safeSmartAccountClient = await signerToSafeSmartAccount(publicClient, {
  entryPoint: '0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789',
  signer: customSigner,
  safeVersion: '1.4.1',
})

const smartAccountClient = createSmartAccountClient({
  account: safeSmartAccountClient,
  chain: chain,
  transport: http(PIMLICO_BUNDLER),
  sponsorUserOperation: pimlicoPaymaster.sponsorUserOperation,
})
```

And then submitting a TX with Pimlico smartAccountClient:

```typescript
const address = smartAccount.account.address
const deployEncodedData = encodeFunctionData({
  abi: creatorTokenFactoryAbi,
  functionName: 'deploy',
  args: [CONFIG],
})
const request = {
  account: smartAccount.account,
  to: FACTORY_ADDRESS as `0x${string}`,
  chain,
  data: deployEncodedData,
}

const hash = await smartAccount.sendTransaction(request)
```

The above works great on Goerli: https://goerli.basescan.org/tx/0x5de8ffda1f5cf8c815d3fb181a25b10ba1b4138f75b417a8bbf0967df3360fae

Not so great on Sepolia: https://sepolia.basescan.org/tx/0x5344489e9ca7c29e6b34ef7fa89e8af2f124b04eebd4acbbd8806d7cb50b3f46

Reverts with reason `GS104` which means "Method can only be called from an enabled module", according to the docs.
Not sure what that means exactly, and what needs to be done to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you need to first enable the module you are trying to interact with from your safe. You can enable modules by using the [`createEnableModuleTx`](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/reference#createenablemoduletx) method from the Safe{Core} SDK's protocol-kit. You can check which modules are enabled by calling [`getModules`](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/reference#getmodules).

You can learn more about modules by reading [this page](https://docs.safe.global/smart-account-modules).

Hope it helps! Louis